# How to create a hash from array

Tags: javascript

What is the simplest (one-line?) way to turn `[1,2,3]` into `{1:0, 2:0, 3:0}`?

**Update:** I would prefer to do it more "functional-style" (one line, with `each` or `map` etc)

Comment: There is no `[1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0]`

Comment: thanks :) the question is fixed

Comment: Still incorrect. You are thinking of `{ 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0 }`

Comment: Right, fixed again (currently in between Ruby and Javascript :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you prefer functional-style? I hope it's not performance.

Comment: @Jack: elegance and self-learning

Comment: [Code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is a much better place for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method allows to pass second argument `initialValue`, to the method. You can send an object as initialValue and keep returning it through the iterations, assigning properties with key set to the current item of array. Beware of type coercion, property keys must be strings in JavaScript. So `toString` method will be invoked upon the items of array in this case.

```
var hash = array.reduce(function(obj,cur){
   obj[cur]=0;
   return obj;
},{});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfaR3/)

In form of one liner:

`var hash = array.reduce(function (obj, cur) { obj[cur] = 0; return obj; }, {});`

Comment: @Engineer: By your logic every script as big as it might be is a one liner :)

Comment: @gryzzly Thx, for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @Engineer sure thing. Now I realise that this method will fail when the items of array aren't unique.

Comment: @Amberlamps I understand,what you mean. But in this case it's *approved on-liner*.

Comment: @Engineer: Brilliant! Marking it as an answer. Too pity that `Array.reduce` is not supported by `mongodb` (version 2.2.1). Any thoughts on that please?

Comment: @gryzzly It does not metter. The OP wants object, and the properties of the object must be unique:)

Comment: @BreakPhreak [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility) can be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

var result = {};
for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l;i++) {
    result[arr[i]] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat, I would prefer to do it more "functional-style" (one line, with `each` or `map` etc)

Comment: Do not loop through an array with `for ... in`

Comment: @Amberlamps That's irrelevant here though, because the arrays are expected to not have gaps in them.

Comment: @Jack: This might be true, but why don´t you want to keep your code consistent? Just stick to the `for(init;cond;inc)` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert your array to a key/value object, with all values set to 0 (as in your example) then you could use:

```
var hash = {};
[1,2,3].forEach(function(item) {
  hash[item] = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't see what's wrong with coding what you need:

```
function objectWithKeysAndValue(keys, value)
{
    var o = {};

    for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i != n; ++i) {
        o[keys[i]] = value;
    }

    return o;
}

console.log(objectWithKeysAndValue([1,2,3], 0);
```

Out of curiosity I ran this function against Engineer's answer and it's twice as fast!

[**Results**](http://jsperf.com/array-fill-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is against most *best practices*, this seems to be neat and foremost, a *one-liner*

```
var foo = [1,2,3];

foo = eval('({' + foo.join(':0, ') + ':0 })' );

console.log( foo ); // Object {1=0, 2=0, 3=0}
```

Comment: +1 for creativity, although not recommending this solution at all :)

Comment: Actually, I don't see any real issue or danger in using `eval` in this instance. But in generell, I'd agree. Its more or less a thought experiment [*And therefore, no reason to downvote @anonymous*]

Comment: at the minimum: measure performance of this method and think what will happen if you have many arrays like this, think of optimisation tools that won't be able to mangle variables inside of eval

Comment: @gryzzly: I don't really get your point. performance of what? `eval` is lightening fast, so is `Array.prototype.join`. Performance is the least worse thing for this snippet.

Comment: @jAndy `eval` is known to be slower, three times slower in case of the code in question – http://jsperf.com/flat-array-to-object I like the creativity of your answer, but the comment about it being not a real issue is something I can't agree with. It's slower, it will mess with optimisation tools, and it is harder to read.

Comment: @gryzzly: I have to agree on that. `Array.prototype.join` also seems to have a bigger impact than I thought [ http://jsperf.com/flat-array-to-object/4 ]. `new Function()` shows the same penalty. However, as stated, I never recommended this pattern as a viable solution.